# amcharts deselect event in column chart when selectWithoutZooming set to true

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I want to clear my start and end points when user deselects the area, when `categoryAxis` set to `selectWithoutZooming = true`

Could you please let me know in which event i can clear the start and end points?

Thanks,
Basha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking into AMcharts documentation i found bellow answer it could be helpfull for someone else

"listeners": [{
                "event": "selected",
                "method": function(event) {
                  var start = event.start;
                  var end = event.end;
                  filterQueryUpdate();
                }},
                {"event":"zoomStarted",
                "method": function(event){
                    clearFilter();
                }}]